# how to find which encoding method is being used

Tags: php, encoding, hex, decoding

I have a php page receiving encoded string with hex values and then with some decoding method get the id from database.
i.e. - this encoded value - 70de63286c26d58f0a9ea5a736447910ee1 becomes this id - 36395756.

Is there an option to figure out which encoding method is being used?

Thanks

Comment: That string looks like a hash, not something that was encoded.

Comment: So there is no way to reverse that hash? I believe this is king of conversion to HEX of the number.

Comment: Hashes are not reversible, so if it is a hash then no. Are you sure it's actually that id? It could just be a GUID used in place of an ID in which case the only place it will match is in the database.